# Spring Cloud Data Flow Local Server + Skipper Server: Error after undeploying streams

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I trying to manage my streams on spring cloud data flow with skipper server.

I followed the instruction here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-deploying-spring-cloud-dataflow

The app registration and stream definition/deployment goes quite well, but after I undeploy the deployed stream, I can't see any stream on the dashboard any more. 
The dashboard shows an error instead:

Could not parse Skipper Platform Status JSON:null

I have to restart the scdf server and skipper server in order to see my stream definition again. 
The version of the components are:

- scdf local server: 1.6.0.RELEASE
- skipper server: 1.0.8.RELEASE
- metrics collector: kafka-10-1.0.0.RELEASE

Some operation details:

1. I registered my app using scdf shell in skipper mode.
2. I defined and depolyed my stream on the scdf dashboard. I undeployed the stream via the stop button on the dashboard, too.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have recently observed this on our side, too, and it has been fixed! [see [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2361](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2361)]

We are preparing for a 1.6.1 GA release, but in the meantime, please feel free to pull the [1.6.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from Spring repo](http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/1.6.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.6.1.BUILD-20180809.163614-5.jar) and give it a go.

If you see any other anomaly, it'd be great to have a bug report on the matter.

Comment: I tried the 1.6.1 package from the link you provided and it works now, thank you!